# Read Certificate from SmartCard using javax.smartcardio

Tags: smartcard, apdu

I need to retrieve a Certificate contained in a SmartCard ISO 7816 compatible. So far I've been able to verify the PIN using APDU commands but I need some pointers for retrieving the certificate. I've tried the following SELECT APDU which should select the first file (as I understand):

```
ResponseAPDU resp = ch.transmit( new CommandAPDU(0X00, 0XA4, 0X00, 0X90, new byte[]{0x54, 0x01}) );
```

However this produces **'6a82'** which is File Not Found. Do I need to provide a file name for it ? Actually I know the certificate name but obviously in String format. Is there a generic APDU command which retrieves the first file contained on the Smart Card ? 
 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've just tried selecting a file with file ID `5401` (hex). That file does not seem to exist, but maybe you need to select an application first (using `SELECT by name` and an AID as "name"). ISO/IEC 7816-4 compatible cards do not use filenames.

It's possible that the card supports ISO/IEC 7816-15 which contains a structure that contains references to the data stored on a card. It may be that your card supports such a structure, but without more information it is hard to tell.

AID for PKCS#15 is `A000000063 504b43532d3135` and the ISO/IEC 7816-15 AID is - euh - missing in action ... comment if you require it :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, right now I've adopted a DLL library which speaks natively with the SmartCard. I don't have much control over it, yet it works. (And without information from the smart cart supplier I guess it's the only choice). Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, normally a PKCS#11 .dll provided by the issuer should do the trick.